# I am trying to create a profile on Contribution Page for membership to include username and password fields for member content on Wordpress site

Tags: wordpress, user

Trying to create a new profile to add to a Contribution Page for memberships which includes fields for username and password for Wordpress member-only content. I cannot select the User Registration or User Account checkboxes for the new profile. There is also no 'Password' type field in the Add fields screen. I have 'Anyone can register' allowed in Wordpress and have CiviCRM Wordpress Member Sync and CiviCRM Profile Sync installed. What am I missing?

[image: New Profile Form]

Comment: does your Profile contain only Contact type fields? ie neither membership nor contribtion type fields

Answer (score 2):

You need to select 'Account creation' option to required or optional under Advance setting of Profile

[image]

Comment: Thanks Pradeep, Account creation required is selected, but does not change the options for "Used for' in section above either before or after the new profile is saved.